# Strange behaviour when using WebView and RelativeLayout in fullscreen

Tags: android, layout, webview, fullscreen

**EDIT:
Here's the video showing the problem: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZZsuMH5T9k](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZZsuMH5T9k) I'm really stuck here :/**

--

I have an activity which consists of a webview and a button at the bottom. I set the window of the activity to fullscreen using this code in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  InstaFetchApplication.applyCurrentTheme(this);

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

  if (UserPreferences.getIsFullScreenReadingEnabled(this)) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // this just do this: window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ActivityUtils.toggleFullScreen(this, true);
  }

  setContentView(R.layout.view_article);

  // ...
}
```

The problem is that *most of the time* the webview seems to "push" the button off the screen. Here's the screenshot:

[image: wrong]

([larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruN5c.png))

What I would expect to see (and *sometimes* I do) is here:

[image: correct]

([larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rY0n.png))

Here's the layout I'm using (note that in my app the top layout has to be a RelativeLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout_test"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Click me!"
  />
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/button"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also noticed that if you turn off all animations on the device using system settings, the issue is gone (though there's this glitch when the whole view has a top margin and then it jumps back in the correct position).

Did anyone encounter similar problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: could you post the `onCreate()`

Comment: You are testing on device or emulator?

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you need a progress dialog in the title bar? `Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS` should be used with `setProgressBarVisibility(true)` or not be used at all if you don't want the progress bar. If you're looking to hide the title bar then you can use `android:windowNoTitle`

Comment: @LalitPoptani The problem occurrs on both the emulator and a device.

Comment: @ManishGupta Sorry, I pasted wrong code at first - I've updated the question with more complete onCreate() method.

Comment: I tried to get exactly your situation and I did manage to solve your issue, see my edited answer below. The issue did not reproduce.

Comment: See the screenshot to convince yourself http://imgur.com/PIsW1

Comment: In the first screenshot (with the cropped button) there is some black space above the webview. Is that a copy/paste error, or does that black space actually exist on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Adding `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` flag to the window solved my problem.

See this post: [flag_fullscreen + windowNoTitle == button focus bug](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2de77043f32835aa/f2a1357bf1335461).

Answer (score 1):

I just added a button to the [Hello WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) tutorial, and everything seems to look right.  Then I converted `main.xml` from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, and everything still seems to look right.  I think you are making things too complicated. :-)  Try removing most of that initialization code from `onCreate()` and just specify it in the XML.

Here is my project.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.hellowebview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

HelloWebViewActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.hellowebview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebViewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_rl);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

main_ll.xml (LinearLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/btn_label"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

main_rl.xml (RelativeLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/mainbtn"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_label"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloWebViewActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">HelloWebView</string>
    <string name="btn_label">Push Me</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: For relative layout android:layout_above="@+id/mainbtn" will not work because you have define buttion below that code

Comment: I can't say whether it should work, but it does work. I tested it on devices running Android 1.6, 2.3, and 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try to align the web view to the parent top, and align the button to the parent bottom *and* to be below the web view. I have found times when, for no real reason, the elements don't quite line up correctly if they are not all strung together in a linear sequence either anchored at the top or at the bottom of the screen.

I presume that you are not overriding the onMeasure() method and changing the measured height of the button. I've created numerous (too many) bugs during development of my apps by miscalculating the height of an element during the layout phase and have spent hours struggling with debugging the layout definition code only to find that it was fine, but the height calculation was feeding invalid data into the layout's rendering phase.

Comment: It seems that this is not the problem of misalignment in the layout. It's as if the framework thought that the whole window is smaller due to the animation of notification bar disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `RelativeLayout` is absolutely necessary, You could change to a `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It should give a better result.

Comment: Thanks but it really has to be RelativeLayout.

Comment: Rather than specifying the mechanism, why not specify the outcome you need to achieve.  Can you explain what design constraint makes non-RelativeLayout solutions infeasible?

Comment: Does it work if you set your WebView to alignParentTop rather than layout_above? The view would be able to extend behind the button rather than pushing it down...

Answer (score 0):

To hide the title bar I use:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Tested on a Galaxy S 2 (Android 2.3.3) and Huawei U8180 X1 (Android 2.2.2) and worked fine with your relative layout.

From the screenshot I have the impression that the problem lies rather with the incomplete progress indicator you requested. The fact that the problem disappears when turning off the animations also supports this theory.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using setFlags with FLAG_FULLSCREEN just didn't include it in the question by mistake. I tried removing FEATURE_PROGRESS but it didn't help.

Comment: What version of Android and what device are you testing on?

Did you ever see the strange behavior with a LinearLayout? I still belief that the black square on top of the bad screenshot has nothing to do with layouting but is a half rendered title or notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. The top layout is still `RelativeLayout`, the only difference with yours is the LinearLayout is wrapping up everything:

```
    <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/layout_test"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="1">
  <WebView

      android:id="@+id/web_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0px"
      android:layout_weight=".90" />


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the `LinearLayout`, `WebView` occupies `90%` of entire window(and parent) and the button remaining `10%`. The height is set to `0px` for both, so the weight can do the work for both of them. The cost for the parsing this xml is insignificant.

And in Java code I did:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
        Button mButton = new Button(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0.10f);
        mButton.setText("Click me!");
        mButton.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        mLinearLayout.addView(mButton);
        mLinearLayout.invalidate();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

below code might help you,

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.setInitialScale(100);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.scrollTo(0, 0);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourdata, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
            // view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        try {
            //your stuff
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```